# C# OrderByDescending

Tags: c#, wpf, arrays, collections

How is the OrderByDescending used ?

I have a label, Circles, declared like this

```
ReadOnlyCollection<FlangeCircle> Circles
```

which contain a variabel, Diameter of the type double

I want to sort them based on the diamter so I try

```
FlangeCircle<FlangeCircle> query = Circles.OrderByDescending(p => p.Diameter);
```

but that will not go throug the compiler, but the following does

```
var query = Circles.OrderByDescending(p => p.Diameter);
```

Why is that and how do I declare query with a "correct" type instead ?

/Stefan

Comment: I imagine the type would be `IEnumerable<FlangeCircle>` not `FlangeCircle<FlangeCirle>` **Edit:** actually just remembered its possibly `IOrderedEnumerable<FlangeCircle>`

Comment: also you can mouse over the var keyword (if your using visual studio) and it should tell you the type the compiler will assign it to

Comment: @Manatherin: you might want to post this as an answer ;)

Comment: @fjdumont, meh jon skeets already done it :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of the variable is the problem:

```
FlangeCircle<FlangeCircle> query = ...
```

`FlangeCircle<FlangeCircle>` doesn't make sense as a type, and certainly isn't what's returned by [`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending.aspx). You almost certainly want:

```
IEnumerable<FlangeCircle> query = Circles.OrderByDescending(p => p.Diameter);
```

Or if you want to be able to perform `ThenBy`/`ThenByDescending` operatorions on `query`:

```
IOrderedEnumerable<FlangeCircle> query = ...;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return an IEnumerable, so:

```
IEnumerable<FlangeCircle> query = Circles.OrderByDescending(p => p.Diameter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the variable by IEnumerable? as in

```
IEnumerable<FlangeCircle> query = Circles.OrderByDescending(p => p.Diameter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `IEnumerable<FlangeCircle> query = ...`